# Match part of a word and order by relevance in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a search on a database ordered by relevance.

Both of the following queries work, only the first one returns no results.

I have tried using IN BOOLEAN MODE but that just makes my title_relevance and desc_relevance fields 0 or 1, and I want to properly rank by how relevant a term is not just whether it appears or not.

Is there any way to achieve this??

Thanks!

1st query:

```
SELECT 
    rcv_id,
    rcv_title,
    rcv_desc,
    (MATCH(rcv_title) AGAINST ('nur*')) AS title_relevance,
    (MATCH(rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nur*')) AS desc_relevance
FROM rc_vacancy
WHERE
    ( MATCH(rcv_title,rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nur*') )
    AND rcv_deleted = 'off'
    AND rcv_active = 'on'
    AND rcv_type = 'P'
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, desc_relevance DESC, rcv_lastupdated
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT
    rcv_id,
    rcv_title,
    rcv_desc,
    (MATCH(rcv_title) AGAINST ('nurse')) AS title_relevance,
    (MATCH(rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nurse')) AS desc_relevance
FROM rc_vacancy
WHERE
    ( MATCH(rcv_title,rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nurse') )
    AND rcv_deleted = 'off'
    AND rcv_active = 'on'
    AND rcv_type = 'P'
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, desc_relevance DESC, rcv_lastupdated
```

Searching for 'nur' without the wildcard also produces zero results:

```
SELECT
    rcv_id,
    rcv_title,
    rcv_desc,
    (MATCH(rcv_title) AGAINST ('nur')) AS title_relevance,
    (MATCH(rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nur')) AS desc_relevance
FROM rc_vacancy
WHERE
    ( MATCH(rcv_title,rcv_desc) AGAINST ('nur') )
    AND rcv_deleted = 'off'
    AND rcv_active = 'on'
    AND rcv_type = 'P'
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, desc_relevance DESC, rcv_lastupdated
```

Answer (score 1):

May it be that the expression in `AGAINST` should not contain a wildcard? You are doing a fulltext search, not a `LIKE`-like query.

Comment: Trying a search without the wildcard returns no results, I have edited the question to show this

Comment: Have you read the manual page for the match search in the MySQL manual? And seen this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Are you referring to ft_min_word_len? If so and the default is 3 characters, a search for 'nurs' still returns no results so I don't think it's that either.